# vim syntastic/phpcs turn off 'style' errors

Tags: vim, configuration, syntastic

I'm using syntastic plugin for vim and one of the checkers phpcs is spamming me with 'style' errors:

Example errors:

`Spaces must be used to indent lines; tabs are not allowed`

`Line indented incorrectly; expected at least 8 spaces, found 2`

Is there anyway to turn off/filter these types of errors, I'm only really interested in syntax errors

Comment: `phpcs` is a style checker.  If you don't want style messages don't use `phpcs`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, you can add this to your .vimrc:

```
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { "type": "style" }
```

Comment: You can also use this interactively, followed by `:SyntasticCheck`.